# Heroku process.env undefined

Tags: node.js, heroku

I was working today on my project and somehow I started to receive an error that says `process.env` undefined. Actually, all vars i configurated in settings now are undefined. Is it a bug on Heroku end or i did something wrong that my `proccess.env` return `undefined`?
Thanks

```
var port = process.env.PORT  || 8080;                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'env' of undefined
```

Comment: This error actually says that `process` is undefined. So it seems like your script is not executed by node.js but something else that does not have a global `process` object.

Comment: Not executed by node.js? I have a nodejs script, for example, it cant be executed by php or other server application :) i got confused!

Comment: It's not a "node.js script", it's a JavaScript file. You can have a browser execute any of your "node.js scripts", the only issue is, that it doesn't define some global values you expect in a node.js environment.

And `process` is one of those, so if it's not available, as is the case here, then there's either something wrong with the particular node.js binary in use or it's not executed by node.js.
The other option would be that someone intentionally set `process = undefined`.

Comment: So u mean that i have installed a module that can overwrite the process var?

Comment: It's unlikely, but possible.

Comment: I found it :) u were right about overwriting the process variable. I have this code:

`if(process === undefined){ var process = {} }` i changed to `if(process === undefined){ let process = {} }` and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You might have defined a function or variable called `process` which shadows over the built in `process` variable, thus `process.env` becomes `undefined` as it refers to your function's `env` property.